# How to insert Line break regex

Tags: regular-expression, line-editor

I have a file which contains one line like this

```
test1.CSV test2.CSV test3.CSV test4.CSV...
```

I want to put a line break after each `.CSV` file name like so

```
test1.CSV
test2.CSV
test3.CSV
test4.CSV
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `tr` utility could be used to replace each space by a newline like so:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <infile >outfile
```

If there are multiple spaces between the filenames on the line, you may compress the generated newlines into single ones using `tr -s`.

This obviously assumes that none of the filenames contain embedded space characters.

You may also achieve the same affect with `sed`:

```
sed 'y/ /\n/' infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/ /\n/g' file
```

where `file` is the name of the file to be edited.

Comment: That requires GNU `sed`.